# How to show TypeScript object in HTML (Ionic/Firebase/Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

How do I display an object in my HTML file? (Using Ionic) It seems fairly simple, but it won't work. I retrieve the object like this, from a snapshot of my database path:

```
this.userPath.subscribe(snapshots => {
  this.snapshotValue = snapshots.val()
  console.log(this.snapshotValue);
})
```

And the console looks something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgFvS.png   (I don't have 'reputation' to post images)

I feel like I've tried everything. Like:

```
<h1>{{snapshotValue}}</h1>  //this returns "[object object]"
<h1>{{snapshotValue.navn}}</h1>  //this gives me an error: "cannot read property navn of undefined"
<h1>{{snapshotValue[0]}}</h1>   //this gives me an error: "cannot read property '0' of undefined.
```

How do I get the individual values from this object?

Comment: To see the object in angular try:
`{{snapshotValue | json}}`

Comment: I actually tried this. And it' kind of works. But this displays the entire object. I don't know how to use this to get one attribute. If I type:
    {{snapshotValue.navn | json}}
it can't find the snapshotValue attribute again.

Comment: looks like you are using an observable.

So please try:

`<h1>{{snapshotValue?.navn}}</h1>`

Comment: @MarcelFrehe Thank you so much! It worked. I've spend so much time on this. You the real mvp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use the async pipe with the elvis operator (?) for observables. Below is using just the elvis.

```
<h1>{{snapshotValue?.navn}}</h1>
```

The elvis operator checks if the object exists before checking for a property on the object.

In the future instead of using this

```
this.userPath.subscribe(snapshots => {
  this.snapshotValue = snapshots.val()
  console.log(this.snapshotValue);
})
```

you can do

```
<h1>{{(userPath | async)?.navn}}</h1>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe
The async pipe does the subscribe and gets the latest value for you

Comment: Thanks you so much! Marcel Frehe commented the same thing. This is excactly what I needed. Cheers.
- unfortunatly I cannot upvote your comment, since I don't have the reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to render the view before the data is available.Try the following method

In your component declare a boolean variable

```
private isDataAvailable:boolean=false;
```

And in your subscribe method make this `true` once the data is available

```
this.userPath.subscribe(snapshots => {
  this.snapshotValue = snapshots.val()
  console.log(this.snapshotValue);
  this.isDataAvailable=true;
})
```

And reneder the template once the data is available using *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="isDataAvailable">
    <h1>{{snapshotValue}}</h1>  
    <h1>{{snapshotValue.navn}}</h1>  
    <h1>{{snapshotValue[0]}}</h1>   
</div>
```

This should do the trick.You can also use async pipe for the same.Find docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: MarcelFrehe just commented a solution for me that worked. But thank you for the reply. This actually fixed another problem I had with the snapshots. Cheers.

Comment: Just a small comment but instead of creating another variable to check if the value is there you could replace the ngIf with snapshotValue

<div *ngIf="snapshotValue">

If the object exists you can then display properties off of it. My below answer goes into a more elegant way to do this though

Comment: Yes could be done as long as its doesn't have initialised data:)

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>{{snapshotValue | json}}</h1>  // this should return you a { stringified json }`

Comment: Also, you could have a look in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) for how and when to use pipes in Angular.